# Dynamically query columns in sqlalchemy with func.count

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm tryying to dynamically build a query in sqlalchemy where the dynamic fields are in the `query` part of the code not the `filter`

```
stats = db.session.query(
func.count(*).filter(table.status==VAL1).label("VAL1"),
func.count(*).filter(table.status==VAL2).label("VAL2"),
func.count(*).filter(table.status==VAL3).label("VAL3"),
).filter(table.uuid==uuid) \
.first()
```

I know this can be done easily with filter by building the filters but I'm not sure how I can accomplish the same with query?

Comment: Why not just `GROUP BY status` instead of running multiple queries?